# java program is printing objects in the wrong order

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to write a class called `RailwayStation` that will print an array of train (using two different classes I wrote called `TIME1`and `Train`. My problem is that I can't understand why the output is arranged in the wrong order.

I assume the problem is in the method inside the class called `addTrain`, which supposed to add a train trip if there exists an empty cell in the array, and if the trip that wishes to be added does not exists already in the array. another method I used (and might be the problem) is called `removeTrain`, which receives a parameter of a train trip and removes that from the array.  My methods `addTrain`, `removerTrain`, and `toString`is as follows:

```
    public class RailwayStation {

        // declrations of final variables
        private final int MAX_TRAINS = 100;
        private final int MIN_VAL = 0;

        // declrations of instant variables

        private Train[] _station;
        private int _noOfTrs;

        /**
         * Empty construter which initialize the instant variables of the class such that the trips array will be in a maximal size
         */
        public RailwayStation() {
            _station = new Train[MAX_TRAINS];
            _noOfTrs = MIN_VAL;
        }

        /**
         * adds a train trip to the trips array
         *
         * @param f the train trip
         * @Returns true if a train trip has been added to the trips array
         */
        public boolean addTrain(Train f) {
            int i, j;
    //        boolean found = false;
            if (isTrainOnSomeStation(f)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                for (j = MIN_VAL; j < _station.length; j++) {
                    if (_station[j] == null) {
                        _station[j] = f;
                        _noOfTrs++;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        // a private method that checks if @param f is null
        private boolean isTrainOnSomeStation(Train f) {
            if (f == null) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = MIN_VAL; i < _station.length; i++) {
                if (_station[i] != null && _station[i].equals(f)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
 /**
     * removes a trip from the trips array
     * @param f the train trip
     * @returns true if the train trip has been removed
     */
    public boolean removeTrain(Train f) {
        int i, j;
        boolean found = false;
        for (j = MIN_VAL; j < _station.length && !found; j++) {
            if (_station[j] != null) {
                for (i = MIN_VAL; i < _noOfTrs && !found; i++)
                    if (_station[i].equals(f)) {
                        _station[i] = _station[_noOfTrs];
                        _station[_noOfTrs] = null;
                        found = true;
                        _noOfTrs--;
                    }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
        /** Returns a string which describes all train in the array as apperas in the arrray
         * @Returns a string of trains as appears in the arrat
         */
        public String toString(){
            String str = "The trains today are:" +"\n";
            if(_noOfTrs == MIN_VAL){
                return "There are no trains today.";
            }
            else {
                String capacity = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < _station.length; i++) {
                    if (_station[i] != null) {
                        if (_station[i].isFull() == true) {
                            capacity = "Train is full";
                        }
                        else {
                            capacity = "Train is not full";
                        }
                        str += _station[i].toString() + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            return str;
        }
    }
```

**In order to call the method `addTrain` I'll be writing:**

```
//Check constructor
        RailwayStation rs = new RailwayStation();

        //AddTrain
        Train f1 = new Train("Haifa",12,0,210,250,250,55);
        Train f2 = new Train("Jerusalem",10,50,210,250,250,40);
        rs.addTrain(f1);
        rs.addTrain(f2);
        System.out.println(rs);

        //RemoveTrain
        rs.removeTrain(f1);
        System.out.println(rs);

        //First Train to Destination
        Train f3 = new Train("Tel-Aviv",11,35,180,100,200,35);
        rs.addTrain(f3);
        Train f3a = new Train("Tel-Aviv",7,15,180,200,200,35);
        rs.addTrain(f3a);
```

**I'm expecting to get the output:**

```
The trains today are:
Train to Jerusalem departs at 10:50. Train is full.
Train to Tel-Aviv departs at 11:35. Train is not full.
Train to Tel-Aviv departs at 07:15. Train is full.
```

**but what I get is:**

```
The trains today are:
Train to Tel-Aviv departs at 11:35. Train is not full.
Train to Jerusalem departs at 10:50. Train is full.
Train to Tel-Aviv departs at 07:15. Train is full.
```

I've tried to use the debugger in order to understand in what part the order gets wrong, but I can't locate the problem.

Comment: How are you calling `addTrain`? Please provide a full [mcve]

Comment: @UnholySheep fixed

Comment: @Jneven your addTrain calls doesn't seem to match with the prints ?

Comment: @LarsNielsen - i'm sorry, you are correct, i fixed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the first trains your array is like so:

```
Train[0] = Haifa...
Train[1] = Jerusalem..
Train[2] = null
Train[3] = null
...
```

Then you remove `Haifa`:

```
Train[0] = null
Train[1] = Jerusalem..
Train[2] = null
Train[3] = null
...
```

Then you add the other trains:

```
Train[0] = Tel Aviv..
Train[1] = Jerusalem..
Train[2] = Tel Aviv..
Train[3] = null
...
```

Does that explain it?

---

The data structure you're trying to build here is a `Stack` - but the good news is that [java already has one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), so no need to do what you are trying to do:

```java
        Stack<Train> trains = new Stack<>();
        Train f1 = new Train("Haifa",12,0,210,250,250,55);
        Train f2 = new Train("Jerusalem",10,50,210,250,250,40);
        trains.push(f1);
        trains.push(f2);

        //RemoveTrain
        trains.remove(f1);


        //First Train to Destination
        Train f3 = new Train("Tel-Aviv",11,35,180,100,200,35);
        trains.push(f3);
        Train f3a = new Train("Tel-Aviv",7,15,180,200,200,35);
        trains.push(f3a);

        String str = "The trains today are:" +"\n";
        for(Train train: trains) {
            str = str + train + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(str);
```